# AMPScript UpdateSingleSalesforceObject only if field is Null

Tags: ampscript

l am using the below to update a field in Salesforce. If the `Survey Score` field is already populated, l don't want it to override. Is this possible?

```
%%[var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Installations__c','a00w000000dIH53','Survey_Score__c','1')
]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retrieve that lead first with [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/retrievesalesforceobjects/) and then depending on what you'll get either update it or not.